# Get and Handle X87 FPU overflow/underflow exception

Tags: linux, assembly, signals, x86-64, fpu

I want to get and handle X87 FPU overflow/underflow exception but failed. 
I wrote a test function and a signal handler:

```
void getStatus() {
    short status;
    __asm__(
        "fnstsw %0\n\t":"=m"(status):"m"(status)
    );
    printf("0x%x\n", status);
}
int fpu(int value) {
    int result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        __asm__(
            "fld %0\n\t"::"m"(value)
        );
        printf("normal\n");
        getStatus();
    }
    __asm__(
        "fstp %0\n\t":"=g"(result):"m"(result)
    );
    return result;
}
void sigHandler(int sig) {
    printf("%s\n", "Get An Exception");
    getStatus();
    return;
}
```

I encountered two problems here:
1. The exception doesn't arise immediately. If I delete the `fstp` , there still should be a floating-point exception for `fld` has been done 9 times. But this didn't occur, the signal handler printed no word. Only if the `fstp` is added can the handler get the signal. And according to the printed status register, the exception status has been set after `fld` 9 times, but sent no signal. 
2. It seems that the status register will be re-initialized to 0 after the exception signal is sent. When the signal handler get the signal, the `getStatus` function always print 0, then I can't get which exception occurs from the status register. 
The output after deleting the "fstp" statement is:

```
normal
0x3802
normal
0x3002
normal
0x2802
normal
0x2002
normal
0x1802
normal
0x1002
normal
0x802
normal
0x2
normal
0xffff82c3
```

The outcome shows that an exception occured, but there is no signal.

Comment: In `"fnstsw %0\n\t": "=m"(status): "m"(status)`, it's pointless to list `status` as an input.  You're telling the compiler you're reading its uninitialized value, but really the asm is using it as a write-only operand.  Same for `fstp`.  But FLD/FSTP modify the x87 register stack, and you're not telling the compiler that those instructions change the x87 stack.  e.g. `double dtmp;`  `asm("fldl %0" : "=t"(dtmp) : "m"(value));` would tell the compiler your asm statement produces a value at the top of the x87 stack.

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't want `fild`?  Or you intentionally want to treat the integer value as a single-precision float (which could thus be NaN and raise an FP exception when used with `fld`).

Comment: I use `fld` here because I can't determine whether the value is an integer in the real scene. I have revised the asm code but it seems that the outcome is not relevant to it.